# How to two views forms intergarte with one controller (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my view file (registration_view.php)

```
<?php echo form_open("user/registration"); ?>
  <p>
  <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name'); ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="<?php echo set_value('last_name'); ?>" />
  </p> 
  <p>
  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
<p>
      <label for="pickup_address">Pick up Address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="pickup_address" name="pickup_address" value="<?php echo set_value('pickup_address'); ?>" />
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="postal_code1">Postal code:</label>
      <input type="text" id="postal_code1" name="postal_code1" value="<?php echo set_value('postal_code1'); ?>" />
      </p>
      <p>
      <input type="submit" class="greenButton" value="Submit" />
      </p>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My controller user.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class User extends CI_Controller{

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_model');

    }

    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->view('registration_view');
    }

public function registration()
{
    $this->user_model->add_registration();
}
}
```

model(user_model.php)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * 
 */
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function add_registration()
    {
        $data=array(
'first_name'=>$this->input->post('first_name'),
'last_name'=>$this->input->post('last_name'),
'email'=>($this->input->post('email'),
'pickup_address'=>$this->input->post('pickup_address'),
    'postal_code1'=>$this->input->post('postal_code1'),
  );
  $this->db->insert('user',$data);
    }
    }
```

This is my application.it is work.i need this view separate to two views.first name,last name and email belongs to one_view.php and others are belongs to another view(second_view.php). click the next button in the one_view.php file then open the second_view.php without going to the value to database.then if click the submit button in second_view.php, all values pass to the user table...please help me how to separate view file by using ajax or jquery.

Comment: I don't know what is _intergarte_: could you fix your title? thank you.

Comment: You can load your view separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to show two view.

Here is how to do it

From your controller to show the first view

```
$this->load->view("one_view",$data);
```

now from within your one_view.php use. you can sow the second view.

```
// from inside one_view.php

<div id="g" style="display:none">
<?php

$this->load->view("second_view",$pass_data);

?>
</div>
```

So you are loading both view from one controller. now to show the second view you can use jquery to show the second view.

and then submit your form or whatevere you have.

Comment: sir , i am not familiar for jquery. i need to use jquery for that.please can u help me from sample coding.

Comment: Post your one_form.php and second_form.php so i can look at your code

Comment: <?php echo form_open("user/registration"); ?>
  <p>
  <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name'); ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>
  <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="<?php echo set_value('last_name'); ?>" />
  </p> 
  <p>
  <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
<p>   (this is a one_form.php)

Comment: <?php echo form_open("user/registration"); ?><p>
      <label for="pickup_address">Pick up Address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="pickup_address" name="pickup_address" value="<?php echo set_value('pickup_address'); ?>" />  (second_form.php)
      </p>
      <p>
      <label for="postal_code1">Postal code:</label>
      <input type="text" id="postal_code1" name="postal_code1" value="<?php echo set_value('postal_code1'); ?>" />
      </p>
      <p>
      <input type="submit" class="greenButton" value="Submit" />
      </p>
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>

Comment: dont paste it here. paste it under your question